# Do I have to add textures back into a material again after changing the properties of the textures it depends on?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

While taking up an existing project, I realized that most of the existing textures are at 2048 x 2048 resolution. This was taking up a lot of memory since the project has a couple hundred textures and a lot of materials that use these textures. I wish to reduce the texture sizes but I am unsure of if the materials using these textures will need me to add the textures back into them individually, which would be the last thing I want to do.

Comment: Try it yourself and see what happens. It takes a minute or 2 to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to add textures back to the material associated with the textures for the future. As long as there's a texture in the material already then you can adjust the texture resolutions. You can even adjust them accordingly per build platform. You can select the texture/image file in Unity hierarchy and do a few things like set platform-specific overrides which will change the texture resolution automatically when you switch platforms fyi.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Comment: This is true for all object references in Unity.  If Unity sees the name/value change (ie, if you do it in the editor) then it will update all of the existing references. =)

Comment: Are there any exceptions to this?